# How to Protect Videos on a VPS for a Membership Site

Tags: python, google-app-engine, vps, cloud-hosting

I am building a membership site using Google App Engine and VPS

1. The site is a membership site built by Google App Engine in Python
2. Videos are stored in a separate VPS. Only members are supposed to have access to these videos.
3. How can I protect my videos from non-members? Even for members, I want to enable expiring download links and IP locked download links.

Any hint on how to do this? I guess I need something like http://www.disposablelinks.com/. Is there any free or open source software with similar features?

BTW: I am using a VPS not Amazon S3 or Google Storage because the bandwidth for cloud service is way too expensive...I have about 30GB videos and 3T bandwidth per month.

Thanks a lot!

=========================================================================

Update: I am thinking about using PHP on the VPS and Googled "PHP hide file path" and got lots of interesting resources. I think I can solve this problem on my own. Any comments or suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Why not store the files in the blobstore? That would make this a lot simpler.

Comment: Thanks 4 this valuable suggestion. But I worry that using Blobstore will consume CPU Time too much and cost a lot of money. I am still reading blobstore manuals.thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

You can put some kind of "marker" into user `cookie`, with value like: `md5(mySecret + IP)` and check it on other server.